# Application doesn`t see JRE

Tags: java, jvm

I used Jar2Exe to convert .jar to .exe. When I run jar, everything works ok. But when I try to run the exe file, it can not find JRE, while there is JRE on the computer. Where may the problem be? The message is "Java Runtime Environment not found". jre is in the path. I used IDE, but there were not such problems before. I do not know what also should be edited.

Comment: Have you checked the [Jar2Exe FAQ](http://www.jar2exe.com/support/faq)?

Comment: I was about to post that exact same comment. Points of interest : make sure you're not trying to execute a 64bytes executable with a 32bytes JVM ; make sure you don't have an irrelevant jre directory next to your executable